# Is it possible to redirect a paused process into a new pipe?

Tags: bash, process

Suppose I have a process that takes some time and outputs some JSON.

```
$: ./foo.py file 

{ ... }
```

And I have piped this output into `jq`:

```
$: ./foo.py file | jq .
```

---

And I say: oh no -- the output is long, and I am in a terminal with no scrolling features -- I'd like to pipe it into `| less`.

But the function has already run for a while.

In the interest of time, is it possible to:

```
(user input) CTRL-Z
(pseudo code) $: fg | less
```

And dynamically append some additional pipeline commands?

Comment: Idea: [`reptyr` the `jq`](https://superuser.com/a/1293299/432690) inside `tmux` which will provide scrolling features.